# Installing SWOOLE in Docker is available, but SWOOLE does not exist when accessing web pages

Tags: php, docker, vue.js, apache, codeigniter

Install SWOOLE in Docker, both "php -m" and "php --ri swoole" can be displayed swoole, and "php Hello.php" also displays true,but website access result is false.

The Hello.php code is as follows:
`<?php var_dump(extension_loaded('swoole'));`

I hope the output result of the webpage is the same as that of the backend output in Docker: bool (true)

Comment: All those "enter image description here" links are distracting. 
Can you clean up your question and lay it out a bit better to make it more readable to those your seeking answers from.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I optimized my question.